# Ubuntu 18.04 Server - Encryption

Tags: server, encryption

I am creating automated install. During the install I want to provide a folder where data can be written which is automatically encrypted and cannot be accessed if the disk was removed.

What is the best approach for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give more info ? You mean like a usb login ? Or a encryption disk that encrypt everything when the key is removed ?

Comment: I mean a folder/partition than encrypts as it is written to. Should someone steal the device in its entirety they would be unable to remove the SSD and mount it on there own PC and read the data on it

Comment: First of all, its always possible to remove the SSD, however if you Encrypt and secure it the right way its impossible to recover the data without the key. If that is what you mean.

Comment: Let me see what you got so far. Because im not going to completely write the script. I can help you out with the encryption part tho.

Comment: I ideally would like to encrypt where it is tied to the hardware. We have a TPM, my understanding is you can use this with bitlocker to encrypt.